# Cannot get serial port working on linux (want to send AT command to an USB attached mobile phone)

Tags: linux, serial-port, usb-modem

I run Kali Linux (Debian based distro), and have `minicom`, `socat`, and `atinout`.
I attached a Samsung Galaxy phone to USB and want to access it, using AT commands.
When I run `dmesg`, I don't see any port, where the phone is attached to.

```
[68106.267643] Generic PHY r8169-900:00: attached PHY driver [Generic PHY]   (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-900:00, irq=IGNORE)
[68106.393299] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[68106.395577] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[68106.396055] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[68106.397738] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
[68108.498714] r8169 0000:09:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[68108.498727] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[68240.791513] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 51 using xhci_hcd
[68240.940501] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=04e8, idProduct=6860, bcdDevice= 2.16
[68240.940507] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[68240.940511] usb 1-1: Product: Galaxy
[68240.940515] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: samsung
[68240.940518] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0149xxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

When I launch `tty`, I see `/dev/pts/6`.

If I configure `minicom` with `/dev/pts/6`, I get nothing, I try to type AT, but never receive a OK!
My phone is rooted and I have USB debugging.

```
Welcome to minicom 2.7.1
OPTIONS: I18n
Compiled on May  6 2018, 08:02:47.
Port /dev/pts/6, 18:58:41

Press CTRL-A Z for help on special keys
```

And if I launch in terminal:

```
echo AT | atinout - /dev/pts/6 -
```

It prints AT in another terminal, not the one I launched in. And I never receive a OK after my AT.

Any idea? Because I cannot communicate with my phone through AT commands.

Comment: `/dev/pts/6` has nothing to do with your phone. It is associated with the terminal (the one you run `tty` in). In general I would expect a serial port connected via USB to be like [`/dev/ttyUSB0`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/usb-serial.txt).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: yes I know this, but how to get my serial port? Normally it should be displayed in `dmesg` or listed in `tty`, but it is not. I don't have any dev/ttyUSB0 neither 1...

Comment: A USB device that emulates a serial link would have a device node such as **/dev/ttyACM0**, and require USB CDC/ACM drivers, which may be missing from your system.  **/dev/ttyUSB0** would be for a USB-to-serial adapter, which is not your phone.  Regardless, the phone is detected as a USB device, but there is no device driver that matches the IDs.

Comment: @sawdust: I did 'sudo modprobe cdc_acm' but still no effevt; and no "/dev/ttyACM0"